# Using the QQ Plot functionality in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm brand new to R, and have a data frame with 8 columns that has daily changes in interest rates. I can plot QQ plots for data each of the 8 columns using the following code:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,4))
for(i in 1:length(column_names)){
  qqnorm(deltaIR.df[,i],main = column_names[i], pch = 16, cex = .5)
  qqline(deltaIR.df[,i],cex = .5)
}
```

I'd like now to use the stat_qq function in the ggplot2 package to do this more elegantly, but just can't get my arms around the syntax - I keep getting it wrong. Would someone kindly help me translate the above code to use ggplot and allow me to view my 8 QQ plots on one page with an appropriate header? Trying the obvious

```
ggplot(deltaIR.df) + stat_qq(sample = columns[i])
```

gets me only an error message

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: sample
Error: stat_qq requires the following missing aesthetics: sample
```

and adding in the aesthetics

```
ggplot(deltaIR.df, aes(column_names)) + stat_qq()
```

is no better. The error message just changes to

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5271)
```

In short, nothing I have done so far (even with Google's assistance) has got me closer to a solution. May I ask for guidance?

Comment: Could you provide a data sample using `dput(head(deltaIR.df, 10))`?

Comment: The `sample` argument should be inside the aesthetics function, e.g.  `ggplot(iris, aes(sample = Sepal.Length)) + stat_qq()`.

Comment: ```
dput(head(deltaIR.df,10))

Comment: ```
dput(head(deltaIR.df,5))``` gives me structure(list(DGS1 = c(0, 0.03, -0.02, -0.01, -0.02, ), DGS2 = c(0.01, 
0.01, -0.01, -0.02, -0.05), 
    DGS3 = c(-0.02, 0.02, -0.02, 
    -0.01, -0.06), DGS5 = c(-0.01, 
    0.01, -0.02, -0.01, 
    -0.08), DGS7 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0, 
    0, -0.09 ), DGS10 = c(0, 0.01, 0, -0.02, 
    -0.07, 0), DGS20 = c(-0.02, 0.02, 0, 
    -0.01, -0.09), DGS30 = c(0.01, 0.02, 
    0, 0, -0.09)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: putting the sample argument inside the aesthetics function ```ggplot(deltaIR.df, aes(sample = deltaIR.df[,i])) + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line()``` works one plot at a time, but when I try and plot all 8 on the same page inside the loop, nothing happens - no plots are produced.